# How to delete a particular XML child node based on their value

Tags: php, javascript, xml

I have an XML structure like this:

```
<document>
    <sliderimage>
        <images>click.bmp</images>
        <images>error_inotherpluginupload.JPG</images>
        <images>dddd.jpg</images>
        <images>Sunset123.jpg</images>
        <images>Water lilies.jpg</images>     
    </sliderimage>
</document>
```

And I'm showing these images like this:

[image: This is how I'm showing the images]

Code for fetching images you can see here :

```
<?php
    $usernmeforxml = $_SESSION['username'];
    $xmlpath = SITE_URL . "xml/" . $usernmeforxml . "/test.xml";
    $xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($xmlpath));
    $sliderimagesinner = $xml->sliderimage->images;
    $imagenum = count($sliderimagesinner);
?>
</br>
<?php
    for ($i = 0; $i < $imagenum; $i++)
    {
?>
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb">
        <img src="../slider_images/<?php 
            echo $sliderimagesinner[$i]; 
        ?>" width="120" height="70" />
        <span>
            <img src="../slider_images/<?php 
                echo $sliderimagesinner[$i]; 
            ?>" width="500" height="350" />
        </span>
    </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<?php
    }   
?>
```

Now i want to delete the image by adding a "delete" button on my images. When clicked,  that image node should be deleted from the above XML file.

All things are dynamic, so it would be very helpful if anyone can help me regarding this.

Comment: Not really an answer because I don't know how to solve this, but if I had this problem presented to me I'd start looking for a solution in PHP's DOM classes, which include a DOMXQuery class.  It ought to be possible with an XQuery to find nodes that meet very specific criteria

Comment: Is it possible to change the structure to add an id attribute for each image? That would make the removal operation less ambiguous.

Comment: @GordonM There is no `DOMXQuery`, but `DOMXPath` should suffice.

Comment: @fab You're right, I meant XPath.  Put that one down to lack of morning coffee :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$usernmeforxml=$_SESSION['username'];
$xmlpath=SITE_URL."xml/".$usernmeforxml."/test.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlpath);   
if($_GET['remove'] == 'true') {
    $myValue = $_GET['file'];
    $xel_array = $xml->xpath("//images[text()='" . $myValue . "']");
    //edited - forgot to double [0]
    unset($xel_array[0][0]);
    file_put_contents($xmlpath, $xml->asXML());
}
```

and a link like

```
<a href="_your_page.php?remove=true&file=your_file_name">remove</a>
```

should do the trick.

Comment: like i am using my query at functions.php, so here in a href i have to put something like that
<a href="functions.php?remove=true&file=your_file_name">remove</a>

Comment: you can add the code to the top of your current file and replace your_page.php with slider.php or whatever your file is called and your_file_name with the name from xml ... eg: Water lilies.jpg. Since your files might have characters that need escape you might want to use urlencode and urldecode.